# How to convert machine learning XGBoost "R" binary model into CORE ML on iOS Swift?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r, machine-learning-model, xgboost

How can we convert our sleep stage classification "R" XGBoost binary model on Windows into CORE ML on iOS to run model on iPhone?

CORE ML doc says it inputs XGBoost -- need guide or tutorial.